# Problem with the ipy.vim script

Tags: python, vim, ipython

I'm trying to use the ipy.vim script to set up a small python dev environment, but I'm running into a connection problem. When I type ipy_vimserver.setup("demo") I get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/IPython/Extensions/ipy_vimserver.py", line 109, in serve_me
    self.listen()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/IPython/Extensions/ipy_vimserver.py", line 93, in listen
    self.socket.bind(self.__sname)
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

When I type it a second time, everything is fine but when I launch gvim the F4/F5 command do nothing and state that they can't connect to the Ipython server.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

Look at the last line of the stack trace: `error: [Errno 98] Address already in use`

**Explanation:**

A nice explanation of `"Address already in use"` error can be found here: ["Bind: Address Already in Use"](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html)

**Possible Solution:**

As I have not tried `ipy.vim` setup myself, from networking point of view, a quick suggestion would be to:

- close/kill both the server (`ipython server`) and the client (`vim running ipy.vim`).
- Restart `ipython server`
- Run vim with `ipy.vim` and try to debug.

**Additional Info:**

- On Linux/Unix machines, the timeout values are defined in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time` and `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_time`
- On Windows machines, this is set in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\TcpTimedWaitDelay`. More details is here: [TcpTimedWaitDelay](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938217.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If I run the exact same code I get the same error. If I change the name from "demo" to, for example, "cookies" it works. Hmm....

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there's already a socket with the name you're trying to create, in this case 'demo'. You need to delete it before doing the ipy_vimserver.setup - in your case, the socket file to delete is  `~/.ipython/demo`

(I'm one of the authors of ipy.vim)